# How to transform a normal Makefile to Qt .pro

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have the below Makefile for a .cpp project using GLUT to do some visualizations. I want to change it to use Qt for visualizations instead. Below is the Makefile for the (working) project

```
OBJECTS     = fluids.o
CFILES      = $(OBJECTS:.o=.cpp)
EXECFILE    = smoke
FFTW        = fftw-2.1.5
INCLUDEDIRS = -I ${FFTW}/include/
LIBDIRS     = $(FFTW)/lib
LIBS        = -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -lrfftw -lfftw
CFLAGS      = -O2 -Wall -pipe -Wno-deprecated-declarations
LINKFLAGS   = 


.SILENT:

all: $(EXECFILE)

$(EXECFILE): $(OBJECTS)
    g++ $(LINKFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXECFILE) -L$(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS)

.cpp.o: $$@.cpp $$@.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEDIRS) -c  $<

clean:
    -rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(EXECFILE)

depend:
    g++ -MM $(CFILES) > make.dep

-include make.dep
```

And this is the .pro file I made in Qt

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = name_of_the_app

QT = core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    window.cpp \
    fluids.cpp \
    simulation.cpp \
    visualization.cpp

HEADERS += window.h

INCLUDEPATH += fftw-2.1.5/include
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/fftw-2.1.5/lib/" -lrfftw -lfftw
```

Now when I build it I get

```
/simulation.cpp:97: error: use of undeclared identifier 'exp'
        f = (fftw_real)exp(-r*dt*visc);
                       ^
```

I assume that the exp() function is declared in rfftw.a or fftw.a and that these do not get added correctly. Is the `LIBS += ...` line correct, if not, how should I change it?

Comment: Isn't `exp()` in `<cmath>`? See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/exp/). I'd assume you need to add `-lm` to `LIBS`, but I'm guessing.

Comment: @user2475059 Thanks, adding #include <math.h>  fixed it. However, I did not need to include it when I built it with g++ and the Makefile, so that's why I thought it was added in the rfftw.a or fftw.a.

Comment: I did a bit of cursory reading on `exp()` and there's apparently a complex version in the STL somewhere. Presumably if your code compiles, it's fine, but on the off-chance FFT is trying to pass a complex variable to `exp()` that happens to also resolve to a `double` or `float` (something TMP'd or coercible?) I can see it leading to wrong results or weird behavior. Just a thing to be aware of.